# Membership doesn't expire for short periods of membership

Tags: civimember

We have standard membership that lasts one year and a trial membership that lasts one week.  The standard membership works fine, but we have found that the trial membership doesn't expire after a week but remains as 'New' for three months.

Looking at the membership status rules, I think I can see why.  'New' membership is set to start on the 'Member Since' date and ends three months after the 'Member Since' date.  Because this rule is listed first the membership remains on the 'New' status for three months even if we have moved past the 'End Date'.

We are using CiviCRM 4.6 on WordPress, but I have also tested this in the demo site running CiviCRM 5.5 on WordPress so I don't think this is version specific.

Has anyone else had this issue?  How did you resolve it?

I am considering changing the order of the status rules as follows:

1. Grace - from End Date to End Date + 1 month
2. Expiry - from End Date
3. New - from Member Since to Member Since + 3 months
4. Current - from Start Date to End Date

Does that sound sensible?

Comment: I have often thought/suggested that we need to be able to do Memb Status on a per Memb Type basis

Answer (score 1):

Your revised order would give them a month of Grace after the one week trial which may not be what you want either.

As per petednz's comment, one set of status rules shared between multiple membership types is limiting.

You could use Status Override to force Expired at the end of the one week membership, possibly with the 'Override until Selected Date' option.

Comment: Yes, good point (about the grace period)! That should have been obvious, but thanks for pointing this out.  I presume, using the status override would have to be a manual process, which won't work for us. We need a system that can work without manual intervention.

Comment: It wouldn't have to be manual - you could do it with an extension or CiviRules (may need to write a custom action) to do something like: if MembershipType == 'trial' and MembershipStatus == 'Grace' then MembershipOverride = true, MembershipStatus = 'Expired'